# Multiple Aggregation in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have three parameters (3 columns)

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2) 
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

and

```
 z <- c(10, NA, 16, 25, 41, NA, 17, 53, 26)
```

I need for each `y` calculate the mean of column `z`, where `x==1`

How can I do it using the `aggregate` function in R?

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
                   y=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                   z=c(10, NA, 16, 25, 41, NA, 17, 53, 26))

data
  x y  z
1 1 1 10
2 1 1 NA
3 2 1 16
4 2 2 25
5 2 2 41
6 2 2 NA
7 1 3 17
8 1 3 53
9 2 3 26
```

Comment: column "SAL"?  What is that?

Comment: It`s column Z. edited

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of going about it, using `tapply`:

```
with(data, tapply(z, list(x==1, y), mean, na.rm=TRUE)['TRUE', ])

#  1  2  3 
# 10 NA 35
```

More generally, to apply an arbitrary function to groups where `x==1`, and return `NA` for groups that *don't* have `x==1`, we can use `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(aggregate(z~y, data[data$x==1,], function(x) {
 c(mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE))
}), list(y=unique(data$y)), all=TRUE)

#   y z.mean z.0% z.25% z.50% z.75% z.100%
# 1 1     10   10    10    10    10     10
# 2 2     NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
# 3 3     35   17    26    35    44     53
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I use function quantile together with mean and write data (mean and quartiles) to csv file?

Comment: You can do anything if you put your mind to it. ;)

Comment: I mean Is it possible to do it in one line?

Comment: @user36363, Have you tried to do any of this yourself? That is totally different from your original question.

Comment: @user36363: I've answered your additional question. In future though, include all relevant information in the question itself, and if you have a separate question, treat it as such rather than updating your question in comments. Also, as Richard pointed out, this is very likely a duplicate, not to mention that `?aggregate` should have made solving your original question pretty trivial.

Comment: OK. Thanks for explanaiton

Comment: @jbaums: But the ?aggregate  alone didn`t help me, since the other functions like merge and aggregate are used there. Could you refer me to the books about that information, please? What books should I learn to come up with your last formula by myself?

Comment: @jbaums,  Hi, one more question, please. I am just interesting how is it possible for example along with calculations of means and quartiles include one more column W and calculate sum of W , for which each Y, where X=1? I mean is it possible to do in one line?

Comment: @user36363: Modify the function (i.e. this bit: `c(mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE))`). There's a clear pattern there. To include the mean in the output vector we do `mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)`. To include the default quantiles we use `quantile(x, na.rm=TRUE)`. To include the sum, we use... I'll leave this exercise to you.

Comment: @jbaums, You described the calculation of the mean and quantiles of column Z. But I mean to consider one more column W and calculate the sum. And to it along with previous calculations.

Comment: @user36363: Ok, do a separate simple `aggregate` or `tapply` (see my first chunk of code) over `W`, and `cbind` the output to the `z` summaries that you generate with my second chunk of code. Please don't keep commenting on this post. If you have new questions, post them as new questions (or find existing SO posts that address your question). All solutions on this post already fully address the present question.

Comment: @jbaums Ok, Thank you! Just last question about the R textbook which you could recommend me?

Comment: @user36363 See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one liner with aggregate for the sake of golf.

```
aggregate(z~y, within(data, z <- ifelse(x==1,z,NA)), mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)
```

It is suboptimal, and it returns NaN instead of NA for y==2 as does mean(numeric(0)).

Comment: since we're playing golf, how bout this: `merge(aggregate(z~y, d[d$x==1,], mean), list(y=1:3), all=T)`?

Comment: @jbaums nice! I'd use also unique(data$y) instead of hard coded 1:3 :-)