# Multiple aggregation in R with 4 parameters

Tags: r, aggregate

I have four vectors (columns)

```
 x y z  t
 1 1 1 10
 1 1 1 15
 2 4 1 14
 2 3 1 15
 2 2 1 17
 2 1 2 19
 1 4 2 18
 1 4 2 NA
 2 2 2 45
 3 3 2 NA
 3 1 3 59
 4 3 3 23
 1 4 3 45
 4 4 4 74
 2 1 4 86
```

How can I calculate mean and median of vector t, for each value of vector y (from 1 to 4) where x=1, z=1,  using aggregate function in R?

It was discussed how to do it with 3 parameters ([Multiple Aggregation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215817/multiple-aggregation-in-r)) but it`s a little unclear how to do it with 4 parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: The biggest problem with trying to use aggregate is that you want different aggregation functions (mean and median). `aggregate()` only really uses one at a time.

Comment: @MrFlick: not really - `aggregate(t~y, data=subset(d, x==1 & z==1), function(x) c(mean=mean(x), median=median(x)))`

Comment: @jbaums - the downside of that of course being that you end up with a matrix inside your dataframe containing columns `mean` and `median`. The structure ends up a bit twisted. Nothing `do.call(data.frame,output)` can't fix, but still a bit of a nuisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in `data.table`

```
data <- data.table(yourdataframe)

bar <- data[,.N,by=y]
foo <- data[x==1 & z==1,list(mean.t=mean(t,na.rm=T),median.t=median(t,na.rm=T)),by=y]
merge(bar[,list(y)],foo,by="y",all.x=T)

   y mean.t median.t
1: 1   12.5     12.5
2: 2     NA       NA
3: 3     NA       NA
4: 4     NA       NA
```

You probably could do the same in  `aggregate`, but I am not sure you can do it in one easy step.

An answer to to an additional request in the comments...

```
bar <- data.table(expand.grid(y=unique(data$y),z=unique(data[z %in% c(1,2,3,4),z])))
foo <- data[x==1 & z %in% c(1,2,3,4),list(
  mean.t=mean(t,na.rm=T),
  median.t=median(t,na.rm=T),
  Q25.t=quantile(t,0.25,na.rm=T),
  Q75.t=quantile(t,0.75,na.rm=T)
  ),by=list(y,z)]
merge(bar[,list(y,z)],foo,by=c("y","z"),all.x=T)

    y z mean.t median.t Q25.t Q75.t
 1: 1 1   12.5     12.5 11.25 13.75
 2: 1 2     NA       NA    NA    NA
 3: 1 3     NA       NA    NA    NA
 4: 1 4     NA       NA    NA    NA
 5: 2 1     NA       NA    NA    NA
 6: 2 2     NA       NA    NA    NA
 7: 2 3     NA       NA    NA    NA
 8: 2 4     NA       NA    NA    NA
 9: 3 1     NA       NA    NA    NA
10: 3 2     NA       NA    NA    NA
11: 3 3     NA       NA    NA    NA
12: 3 4     NA       NA    NA    NA
13: 4 1     NA       NA    NA    NA
14: 4 2   18.0     18.0 18.00 18.00
15: 4 3   45.0     45.0 45.00 45.00
16: 4 4     NA       NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do that but got the error:
unused argument (by = y)

Comment: Did you make it into a ```data.table``` object first?

Comment: Do you want when x=1 AND where z=1..or do you want do you want when x=1 OR when y=1? That could be the difference.  If not, you are going to have to post the desired output because it is unclear to me.

Comment: It works now, I want to do it for x=1 AND z=1. And under these conditions y can be equal only to 1 and I get one row in results for where y=1, But how can I get results for each y, for example if y=2,3,4 I need get NA in results.

Comment: Thank you. That`s good. I`m just beginner in R and wondering if it is possible to do the following: we got for rows for z=1 but can we do another 4 rows for z=2,3 and 4 and to it in one formula? to get 16 rows in result

Comment: just added it to the answer

Comment: Thank you! In that example you calculate mean and median, but is it possible to calculate quantiles as well? I tried to do it but got the error

Comment: yeah..adding quantiles or standard deviations is easy.  see above. please mark this as answered.

Comment: Hello Mike. I like your method and I used it a lot. But I have one more question. We have the same data and we need to make groups by Y and Z, but not for each number from Z, but split Z by groups: if 0 < z <= 2 group I, 
           if 2 < z <= 3 group II and 
           if 3 < z <= 4 group III.
                               And do all the same calculations but for those three groups. Thank you!

Comment: Just change the ```by``` statement slightly.  Instead of ```by=list(y,z)]```, use ```by=list(y,z.grp=cut(z,c(-Inf,2,3,Inf))]```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for your help, Your approach is the most simple, I like it. I have one more question nobody can answer, please take a look at it, thanks in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697468/conditional-calculating-the-numbers-of-values-in-column-with-r