# Conditional calculation of means of different columns in data.table with R

Tags: r, list, aggregate, data.table

Here was discussed the question of calculation of means and medians of vector t, for each value of vector y (from 1 to 4) where x=1, z=1, using aggregate function in R.

```
 x y z  t
 1 1 1 10
 1 0 1 15
 2 NA 1 14
 2 3 0 15
 2 2 1 17
 2 1 NA 19
 3 4 2 18
 3 0 2 NA
 3 2 2 45
 4 3 2 NA
 4 1 3 59
 5 0 3 0
 5 4 3 45
 5 4 4 74
 5 1 4 86
```

[Multiple aggregation in R with 4 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226243/multiple-aggregation-in-r-with-4-parameters)

But how can I for each value (from 1 to 5) of vector x calculate (mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t)) ? And do not make calculations for values 0 and NA in any vector. For example, in vector y the 3rd value is 0, so the 3rd number in every vector (y,z,t) should not be used. And in result the the third row (for x=3) should be NA.

Here is the code for calculating means of y,z and t and it`s needed to add the formula for calculation (mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t)):

```
data <- data.table(dataframe)
bar <- data[,.N,by=x]
foo <- data[ ,list(mean.y  =mean(y, na.rm = T),
                   mean.z=mean(z, na.rm = T),
                   mean.t=mean(t,na.rm = T)),
             by=x]
```

In this code for calculating means all rows are used, but for calculating  (mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t)), any row where y or z or t equal to zero or NA should not be used.

Comment: Does it need to be a `data.table` solution specifically? Also what do you mean by "in result the the third row (for x=3) should be NA"?

Comment: @KaraWoo No, it is not necessary to use data.table ? But I use csv file for data. So result should be in form of vector with 5 values (for each number of X). For example, for x=1, we have two rows of numbers, but for calculating (mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t)) for x=1, we should use only first row for every vector, since in the second row y=0. For x=5 we have 4 rows of data,and one of them contains zeros. So, for calculating (mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t)) we should use only 4 last rows of every vector. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update:

Oh, this can be further simplified, as `data.table` doesn't subset `NA` by default (especially with such cases in mind, similar to `base::subset`). So, you just have to do:

```
dt[y != 0 & z != 0 & t != 0, 
    list(ans = (mean(y) + mean(z))/(mean(z) - mean(t))), by = x]
```

---

FWIW, here's how I'd do it in `data.table`:

```
dt[(y | NA) & (z | NA) & (t | NA), 
        list(ans=(mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t))), by=x]
#    x         ans
# 1: 1 -0.22222222
# 2: 2 -0.18750000
# 3: 3 -0.16949153
# 4: 4 -0.07142857
# 5: 5 -0.10309278
```

Let's break it down with the general syntax: `dt[i, j, by]`:

In `i`, we filter out for your conditions using a nice little hack `TRUE | NA = TRUE` and `FALSE | NA = NA` and `NA | NA = NA` (you can test these out in your R session).

Since you say you need only the non-zero non-NA values, it's just a matter of `|`ing each column with `NA` - which'll return TRUE only for your condition. That settles the subset by condition part.

Then for each group in `by`, we `aggregate` according to your function, in `j`, to get the result.

HTH

Comment: Hi Arun. How can I do the same calculations by groups x, y and z, but z split by subgroups:   if 0 < z <= 2 group I, 
  if 2 < z <= 3 group II and 
  if 3 < z <= 4 group III.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
# create your sample data frame
df <- read.table(text = " x y z  t
 1 1 1 10
 1 0 1 15
 2 NA 1 14
 2 3 0 15
 2 2 1 17
 2 1 NA 19
 3 4 2 18
 3 0 2 NA
 3 2 2 45
 4 3 2 NA
 4 1 3 59
 5 0 3 0
 5 4 3 45
 5 4 4 74
 5 1 4 86", header = TRUE)

library('dplyr')

dfmeans <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(y) & !is.na(z) & !is.na(t)) %>% # remove rows with NAs
  filter(y != 0 & z != 0 & t != 0) %>% # remove rows with zeroes
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(xmeans = (mean(y) + mean(z)) / (mean(z) - mean(t)))
```

I'm sure there is a simpler way to remove the rows with NAs and zeroes, but it's not coming to me. Anyway, `dfmeans` looks like this:

```
#   x      xmeans
# 1 1 -0.22222222
# 2 2 -0.18750000
# 3 3 -0.16949153
# 4 4 -0.07142857
# 5 5 -0.10309278
```

And if you just want the values from xmeans use `dfmeans$xmeans`.

Comment: Thank you. But what if we have one more column W, which contains numbers from 1 to 4 only, and we need to make the same calculations but for W=1 only.

Comment: You can add another `filter` line: `filter(W == 1)`

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting solution, never worked with `filter` function

Comment: The whole `dplyr` package is incredibly useful, I highly recommend checking it out. If my solution worked for you you can accept the answer. :)

Comment: I have the last question, please. For example, we have vector x(from 1 to 5), y and w (from 1 to 4). How can I calculate the number of values in y for each x, for w=1? In example above if x=2, the number of values in y equal to 3( don`t count NA)