# Conditional calculation of means of different columns in data.table with R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregation

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226243/multiple-aggregation-in-r-with-4-parameters) was discussed the question of calculation of means and medians of vector *t*, for each value of vector *y* (from 1 to 4) where *x* = 1, *z* = 1, using the `aggregate` function in R.

```
 x y  z  t
 1 1  1 10
 1 0  1 15
 2 NA 1 14
 2 3  0 15
 2 2  1 17
 2 1 NA 19
 3 4  2 18
 3 0  2 NA
 3 2  2 45
 4 3  2 NA
 4 1  3 59
 5 0  3 0
 5 4  3 45
 5 4  4 74
 5 1  4 86
```

But how can I calculate `(mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t))` for each value (from 1 to 5) of vector *x* and not make calculations for values `0` and `NA` in any vector? For example, in vector *y* the 3rd value is 0, so the 3rd number in every vector (*y,z,t*) should not be used. And in the result the third row (for *x* = 3) should be `NA`.

Here is the code for calculating means of *y,z* and *t*, and it's needed to add the formula for calculating `(mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t))`:

```
data <- data.table(dataframe)
bar <- data[,.N,by=x]
foo <- data[ ,list(mean.y  =mean(y, na.rm = T),
               mean.z=mean(z, na.rm = T),
               mean.t=mean(t,na.rm = T)),
         by=x]
```

In this code for calculating means all rows are used, but for calculating `(mean(y)+mean(z))/(mean(z)-mean(t))`, any row should not be used where *y* or *z* or *t* equal zero or `NA`.

Comment: This is OT for [stats.se] as it doesn't really address a *statistical* issue or problem. I appreciate that you are doing a data analysis but the solution to your question is restricted to simply finding the right incantation to make R do what you want. Such questions, as I mentioned, are OT here, but this would be suitable on [so].

Answer (score 0):

You can subset your data first.

```
subdata <- data[which(data$y != 0 & data$z !=0 & data$t !=0 & 
!is.na(data$y) & !is.na(data$z) & !is.na(data$t)),]
```

Now you have a subset of the original data frame that does not include rows with 0 or NA. Then you can aggregate "subdata" by x applying your user-defined function.